# Skype putting messages in random places/times

Tags: windows-7, iphone, skype

I am skyping someone who is on an iPhone (I am on Windows 7), and his messages are getting placed in random places in the conversation window (as if he is time travelling and messaging me).

The times are sporadic, too; there is no rhyme or reason, though some will work and come through just fine (at the end of the conversation, as expected). When a message *does* get jumbled up, however, the Skype taskbar icon will flash with a gold background as if there is a message, but the little number that indicates the number of messages doesn't appear.

It **only** happens with this person, and it gets to a point where the messages are so randomly placed I can't even find them and we have to resort to text.

Is there a reason behind this?

**EDIT:** It is now doing this with 3 people, all on mobile devices.

Comment: Probably this has something to do with clock settings. Is his clock correctly set? Is your clock correctly set? What about time zones? Hope this helps ;-)

Comment: Yes and yes. He's only an hour behind me; it's never been an issue before.

Comment: Could it be that an update messed things up? (I'm just guessing here).

Comment: It's been like this for a month or so; I would have no way of knowing :P

Answer (score 1):

Skype links to a [mid-Dec. 2012 bug report of chat messages being out of order](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-archive/Skype-Messages-Out-Of-Order/td-p/1312417) in [its description of](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Update-7-18-Bringing-chat-messages-in-order-again/td-p/4259219) what version 7.18, released today, is supposed to fix.

See also: [Why are Skype messages showing up out of order?](https://superuser.com/questions/1024860/why-are-skype-messages-showing-up-out-of-order/)